# Symbol 'jquery.include_datepicker' is not defined

Tags: jquery, tapestry

I have a similar question with [this](http://git.net/ml/users-tapestry-apache/2014-11/msg00207.html) guy, but there is still no answer there.

Maybe cool guys in SO can help me. Thanks in advance.

Here is my contributeJavaScriptStackSource in AppModule.java

```
public static void contributeJavaScriptStackSource(MappedConfiguration<String, JavaScriptStack> configuration, @Symbol(JQuerySymbolConstants.SUPPRESS_PROTOTYPE) boolean suppressPrototype) {
    configuration.overrideInstance("core-datefield", JQueryDateFieldStack.class);
}
```

Comment: Can you share a bit of your code?

Comment: @Lissy edited..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to define a value for this symbol using one of the symbol providers, i.e. `ApplicationDefaults`:

```
public static void contributeApplicationDefaults(
        MappedConfiguration<String, Object> configuration)
{
    // ... set it to "true" or "false" explicitly
    configuration.add(JQuerySymbolConstants.INCLUDE_DATEPICKER_I18N, "true");
}
```

If set to "true" the library will try to use localized messages, [source code is here](https://github.com/got5/tapestry5-jquery/blob/7efe8483676968971df592711d270dd21720b544/src/main/java/org/got5/tapestry5/jquery/services/javascript/JQueryDateFieldStack.java#L152).